# Big Commerce - Pull blog articles from outside blog page

Tags: bigcommerce

In the default Cornerstone theme I see that there is a blog.html file that pulls a number of blog posts. But what if I want to pull blog posts from outside of that page? For instance, what if I wanted to show a list of latest posts, or posts with a specific tag on an individual post, or a completely different page?

I saw that there's an api endpoint for blog articles here  https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/marketing/store-content-api/blog-posts/getallblogposts and I'm attempting to get that data with this ajax query

```
$.ajax({
    url: `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/store-hash/v2/blog/posts`,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    headers: {
        'X-Auth-Client': 'client-code',
        'X-Auth-Token': 'token',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3003',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    },
}).done((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But wouldn't this method be unacceptable because it would present my api keys to the front end?

Is there a safe way to get a list of all blog articles from outside the blog page?

Comment: Can someone explain why my post got downvotes so I can properly edit the question? I thought I was fully following stackoverflow's guidelines. Stating the question, showing research I've done, and code I've written.